# How to return the items in MYSQL greater than 6 months?

Tags: mysql, date, select

How do I return items in MYSQL based on the Timestamp column great than six months and delete them?  I'd like to be able to delete items in the table that are greater than six months so that the table doesn't keep growing .. what's the exact query for that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a query to find all rows older than 6 months based on the value of a timestamp column:

```
select id
from your_table
where your_timestamp_column <= (now() - interval 6 month);
```

Comment: Or even better, `DELETE ...`

Comment: you are too fast in answering the Ques. :O

Comment: @eggyal I wouldn't necessarily recommend deleting all of the rows older than 6 months in a single query, depending on the data volume, concurrent queries on the server, etc. Often it's safer to do the deletes on a passive DB or to delete smaller chunks using a tool like pt-archiver: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-archiver.html

Comment: @PHP_loverIt's "6 month", just like in my example. Here's a quick query you can run for yourself to see how it works: `select (now() - interval 6 month);`

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

Using **DATEDIFF** function:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName  
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), colName) > 180;

DELETE FROM tableName  
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), colName) > 180;
```

Using **DATE_SUB** function:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName  
WHERE colName < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);

DELETE FROM tableName  
WHERE colName < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```